# Where is the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Basic NuGet package?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I can't seem to find the NuGet package for the released version of Microsoft.Owin.Security.Basic. I would expect it to be on nuget.org, but it isn't. According to the Katana project site Microsoft.Owin.Security.Basic was released with v2.0.0.0 in 2013.

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=roadmap

Does anyone know where I can find the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Basic NuGet package or at least what happened to it?

**EDIT**

Just in case anyone else is having the same problem, I just posted this to the Katana Project.

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/381

Comment: Is it not contained in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security/ ?

Comment: No I checked that packaged. It seems to include common security classes consumed by all of the other security middleware projects. I also poked around the Microsoft.Owin.Security source to see if maybe they just moved the Basic classes into the project, but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response for the Katana Project and it looks like the basic security middleware was never released. Here is the response from the issue I opened.

http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/381

> That roadmap description was an out of date description of what we
>   initially planned to ship for v2.0, not what actually shipped with the
>   release. The Security.Basic package was never shipped because basic
>   auth does not meet our security requirements. I've updated the roadmap
>   description accordingly.